# Android send intent issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I have added intent-filter to my activity, so I can receive send intents that contain text, I have set data to text/plain, everything works fine, I can choose my application from the picker, it is opening, showing me the text, but, when I minimalize my app, and then click again on ColorNote application (I am using it to take my notes) it is opening my app instead of ColorNote, anyone ever had similiar issue? And know how to resolve it?

@Edit
Do not know why I am getting - points, if you think it is easy question you could write how to solve it instead of giving -.
By the way, I don't think any code is neccessary in here right now.

Comment: it is not an issue. This is the way it should behave.

Comment: Well I tested other apps, they do not behave like that, thats what bothers me

Comment: have you tried calling finish() after you send that intent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way it should behave. For e.g. if an application starts another and you leave the application without closing it's task you will return to the intent it started. I can reproduce this with apps which take me to the play store:

What I did:

**First test:**

1. Start application
2. Let it start the Play Store
3. Press Home
4. Start the application again
5. welcome back to the app store

**Second test:**

1. Start application
2. Let it start the Play Store
3. Close application (Task Manager)
4. Start the application again
5. welcome back to the application

Okay now on how to solve your problem. I would check if my application was started by another intent -> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

```
boolean wasStartedByOtherApp = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
        wasStartedByOtherApp = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(wasStartedByOtherApp){
        finish();
    }
}
```

I have not tested this. This should just give you an idea on how to solve the issue you are facing. But be warned as an android user I would be *angry* if an application closes itself just when I want to check my calendar if I have time and would like to return to the intent the app just started.